# Socket.IO can't connect to server when running Express

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, http-status-code-404

I am trying to write a little app using Node.js, Express.js and Socket.IO.

The server runs fine and I can serve HTML and other static content. But I'm having a hell of a time getting the clients to connect via Socket.IO to the server.

When I don't use Express it works fine, but with Express I can't seem to get everything to cooperate. I am not sure if there are some special considerations when using Express and Socket.IO in conjunction.

Part of me thinks this could be a route issue?

It looks like when the socket tries to connect it is 404'ing:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/socket.io/1/?t=1403186531515 400 Bad Request 1ms
```

Server code:

```
var express = require('express')
  , app = express()
  , http = require('http')
  , server = http.createServer(app).listen(3000)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(server)
  , favicon = require('static-favicon')
  , logger = require('morgan')
  , cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
  , session = require('express-session')
  , routes = require('./routes/index')
  , path = require('path')
  , bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hjs');

app.use(favicon());
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({secret: 'keyboard cat'}));
app.use(require('less-middleware')(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});

// error handlers
// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('error', {
            message: err.message,
            error: err
        });
    });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: {}
    });
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    //message new connection
    socket.emit('message', { message: 'Message from server.' });
    //message all connections
    socket.on('send', function (data) {
        io.sockets.emit('message', data);
    });

});
```

Client code:

```
** html and other js omitted **

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/0.9.16/socket.io.min.js"></script>  
<script>
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
</script>
```

I have also tried

```
var socket = io.connect('ws://localhost:3000');
```

To no avail.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: ^First im hearing of it, ill check it out. Thanks.

Comment: Express.io is rather outdated and isn't updated anymore.

Comment: Any similar alternatives?

Comment: Where you able to resolve this? I'm having the same issue now

Comment: I was not able to resolve it, but I haven't tried again in quite while so I will be revisiting some of the answers here.

Comment: @BenFortune What`s better in your opinion atm?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you use CDN on client, but you can use the local resource (served in backstage by socket.io)

So replace your script tags with:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io.connect(); // or just io();
</script>
```

You can get more help in Socket.io [Get Started simple chat example](http://socket.io/get-started/chat/)

Comment: It doesn't matter where the browser fetches the socket.io library from. No connections to a socket.io server occur during that step. What matters is the next step: how they connect. The failed GET request to "http://localhost:3000/socket.io/1/?t=1403186531515" posted above indicates socket.io was loaded but is having trouble connecting to a websocket server. If that weren't the case, we'd see a failed GET request to "http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/0.9.16/socket.io.min.js" instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try swapping the order of when you bind the server to a port:

```
var express = require('express')
  , app = express()
  , http = require('http')
  , server = http.Server(app)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(server)

server.listen(3000);
```

Shoutout to Doug Wilson for [his comment on GitHub](https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io/issues/1556#issuecomment-48119621) which helped me solve this issue.

Answer (score -1):

just try :

```
var socket = io.connect();
```

Comment: Didn't change anything